# emacs interactive search search-forward-regexp difference

Tags: regex, emacs

I have a couple of regular expressions that work fine using Emacs' interactive search.  They are "^\." and "^#".  They search for a period and a hash at the beginning of the line.

I'm trying to write an interactive function that searches for these regular expressions on a line but I'm failing.  My function is

```
(defun line-contains (regexp)
  "Return true if the current line contains the passed regular expression."
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-line)
    (search-forward-regexp regexp (point-at-eol) t)))
```

When I call

```
((or (line-contains "^\.")
     (line-contains "^#"))
```

on the following line

```
if ($default)
```

it returns true even though that line doesn't match the regular expressions when called by interactive search.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the backslash in the string literal, like this

```
((or (line-contains "^\\.")
     (line-contains "^#"))
```